# What is the represention for calling function in stack?

Tags: stack

Today I have read an article which is about golang goroutine. It says that if there are too many recursive call, the goroutine space will be extended. In my mind, while program running, each function call will create a new stack, system only push a pointer-like object(some mechine code) which point to the created stack to caller function stack top. When cpu load this object, it will save current context and jump to created stack. After called function having returned, cpu will write the returned value which is in register back to the object. If my understanding is right, there is only a little space cast for recursive function call at calling stack. As reading that article, I doubt my understanding is wrong. May each function call make the whole called function code been pushed into calling function stack but not a pointer-like object. If this is true, a function call will cast much space at calling stack. I searched this question by google, but no result. Is there anyone can help me?

**Update:** I found the answer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/.

Comment: There is not much stack space overhead for the single function itself, but the function being called might have a lot of local variables so each stack frame could be big, and in the case of recursion you can have a lot of those stack frames, so eventually it adds up.

Comment: "May each function call make the whole called function code been pushed into calling function stack" The *code* of the function is not being pushed, but all its local variables live there.

Comment: @Thilo 2 questions:

Comment: @Thilo 2 questions: <1>If only local variables in stack, where is code stored in memory? There must be some place to keep code and maintain the running order of it. <2>. According to your said, if not in concurrent program, there is only 1 stack for per program(ex. the main function in C)?

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for your comment. I think I found the answer. Earlier I deem mechine code( the text segment) is stored in stack, now your comment make me found the answer. Thank you

Comment: and yes, there is one stack per thread, so if you are single-threaded, then there is only one stack